# How to let Facebook approve a permission that's intended to be private (e.g. CMS to FB pages integration through manage_pages permission)

Tags: hybridauth, facebook-app-center

We want to integrate our own CMS with our own social identities pages to automate the process of publishing our articles to Facebook and Twitter.
To do so we used a system based on PHP HybridAuth scripts.
For Twitter no problems.
Facebook now requires a specific review for each permission outside the basic ones.
We need the manage_pages permission to let the cms automatically manipulate our own pages.
Facebook requires a review with step to step instruction to simulate the functionality so they can approve it or not.
But how can I simulate something that's intended to be private and available only to our staff?
Do I need to mimic the flow in a public directory to just have the permission approved, or is there a better way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your config.php file to include the option `"scope" => "manage_pages"` in your facebook provider.

```
return 
   array(
     /*...*/ 

      "providers" => array ( 

        "Facebook" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "xx", "secret" => "xx" ),
            "trustForwarded" => false,
            "scope" => "manage_pages"
        ),
    /*...*/
```